# The nearest bars and restaurants from the retrofit on api google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, retrofit

i want to find nearest bars and restoraunts from me on api google maps, and put it in listView and on map, i do it with retrofit, bit i have an error,, but i cant understand how i must to do, can you help me?

**UPD** all code:

**UPD** add adapter code

public class Retrofit {

```
private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static ApiInterface apiInterface;

interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/nearbysearch/json?location=49.9944422,36.2368201&radius=500&types=food&key=AIzaSyDQZoJKznf0uRkvJFqLYbZ7-1GeGudjmv0")
    void getBars(Callback<PlaceResponse> callback);


}

static {
    init();
}

private static void init() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
    apiInterface = restAdapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
}

public static void getBars(Callback<PlaceResponse> callback) {
    apiInterface.getBars(callback);
}
```

}

Class Result:

```
public class Result {

public Geometry geometry;
public String icon;
public String id;
public String name;
public OpeningHours openingHours;
public List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
public String placeId;
public String scope;
public List<AltId> altIds = new ArrayList<AltId>();
public String reference;
public List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
public String vicinity;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getVicinity() {
    return vicinity;
}

public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
    this.vicinity = vicinity;
}
```

}

Class Place Response:

```
public class PlaceResponse {

public List<Object> htmlAttributions = new ArrayList<Object>();
public List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
public String status;
```

}

Call and set in adapter:

```
 Retrofit.getBars(new Callback<PlaceResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void success(PlaceResponse placeResponse, Response response) {
            listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, placeResponse // There is error));
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Error:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Adapter code:

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Result> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Result> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textNameOfBar = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name_id);
            holder.textVicinity = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.vicinity_id);

            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        Result result = getItem(position);
        holder.textNameOfBar.setText(result.getName());
        holder.textVicinity.setText(result.getVicinity());


        return rowView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        public TextView textNameOfBar;
        public TextView textVicinity;

    }


}
```

Comment: my bad , now addad

Comment: so basically this error is caused when your API key does not contain the corresponding ip address in developer console. add your ip address there against your API key and after few minutes try!. It will work perfecty

Comment: Consider using the Android API for this: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker

Comment: Ken Wolf, in picker i cant filter for just bars and restoraunts

Comment: prabhat yadav, where i must to add ip in console?

Comment: you probably got this already, but if the error is " BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $" then you're likely expecting an Array when in reality you're getting an object. In this case you get a DTO that has a field called "results" - which gives you your results

Answer (score 0):

You received the error because your expected result (`List<Bars>`) isn't what the server is returning (i.e you're excepting an json array but the server returns an json object).

The [place search documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResponses) shows that the response has a given format encapsulating the results. In this case, the model class should like this:

```
public class PlaceResponse {

    public List<Object> htmlAttributions = new ArrayList<Object>();
    public List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
    public String status;
}

...

public class Result {

    public Geometry geometry;
    public String icon;
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public OpeningHours openingHours;
    public List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
    public String placeId;
    public String scope;
    public List<AltId> altIds = new ArrayList<AltId>();
    public String reference;
    public List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
    public String vicinity;

}
```

with `void getBars(Callback<PlaceResponse> callback);` in your API interface.

You can use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate your model classes from a json schema.

Also, please note that the food type is deprecated (see [Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1)).

then in your retrofit callback you can do to access the results:

```
    @Override
    public void success(PlaceResponse placeResponse, Response response) {
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, placeResponse.getResults()));
    }
```

Comment: and what should I do in the adapter ? there is a bug in the update added, also added new classes

Comment: @Azarnoy simply use the results inside your `PlaceResponse`, that's the objects you want to use. I updated my answer with correct code.